# UIButton causing a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm having a bit of a problem here.  I've created a button and want it to change it's backgroundImage on being clicked.  It's not working and I get a SIGABRT error.

The code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
if ([sender isSelected])
{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"]];
}
else
{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"]];
}
```

}

Comment: FYI: This sort of problem becomes obvious when you type sender instead of allowing it to be the generic type: `indicatedButton:(UIButton *)sender` here, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage ....] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here's the relevant Apple documentation on the method: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage%3aforState):

So in your case, it would be:

```
- (IBAction)indicatedButton:(id)sender
{

    if ([sender isSelected])
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

Assuming here that "sender" is actually a UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast sender as UIButton because sender is (id) and the object you want is UIButton so
put this line in your code`UIButton *btn=sender;`

```
- (IBAction)indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn= sender;
    if ([btn isSelected])
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify you're getting a UIButton

```
-(IBAction indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
    }
}
```

Convention tip: best practice for properties of an object is to use dot notation (isSelected is a BOOL property of UIButton)

```
-(IBAction indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (sender.isSelected)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If you're just using a regular button, but what you want is a "toggle" button (it's one image, or a different image), then you need to set the selected state property for the button, so that it -knows- it's selected after it's been touched (and vice versa if it isn't)

```
-(IBAction indicatedButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        if (sender.isSelected)
        {
            [sender setSelected:NO]; // if we were selected, we won't be now
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"];
            [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (!sender.isSelected)
        {
            [sender setSelected:YES]; // if we aren't selected, we will be now
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"];
            [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using introspection (the checking class types), if you know you want to work with a button, you could also change the button sender type from id to UIButton. You can do this without rewiring the button to the storyboard/nib

```
-(IBAction indicatedButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
        if (sender.isSelected)
        {
            [sender setSelected:NO]; // if we were selected, we won't be now
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"completeTickBox.png"];
            [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if (!sender.isSelected)
        {
            [sender setSelected:YES]; // if we aren't selected, we will be now
            UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blankTickBox.png"];
            [sender setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}
```